# Creating Decision Tree in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I have a data set with PinNumbers, Cities, Individual Names, Start Data, Variance1, Variance2, Variance3.

I am wanting to use a decision tree to analyze this data in R. I used code:
`fit <- rpart(City ~ Variance1 + Variance2 + Variance3, 
             data = [data set name], model = 'class')`

From here I am not sure where I need to go with this to get what I am looking for. I would like to create a decision tree based off the data showing the variance and how they are affected by the different cities.

Comment: What are you looking for? Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. A minimal working example is always helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If your question is more about Stats than Programming, you might have better luck in Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/